# Find entity for @OneToMany with global condition

Tags: hibernate, select, jpa, global

I have entity Task which has many Params. I want for each query receive only that Tasks which have Param with name 'xyz'.

- I can't create view
- I want get ONLY Tasks wich contain Param with name 'xyz'
- I want get all Params. Not only with name 'xyz'
- I want have this behavior globally (for each new query too). So it can/should be placed in Entity meta data.
- I can get params eagerly.
- I don't want put extra condition for each query.

I use Hibernate 4

**Task.java**

```
@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "params")
    @JoinColumn(name = "taskId")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    List params = new ArrayList();
}
```

**Param.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class Params {

    String name;

}
```

Comment: What did you try already?  Hql or criteria?  Error message?

Comment: @Where annotation, but I can restrict based on fields in Task entity. Don't want use query builder because ill need add this for queries. So best solution is to put this configuration into Entity class (Task)

Comment: Also maybe a possibility: Filters : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html